# How to change the font of the numbers?

Tags: beamer, siunitx, computer-modern, angle, degrees

Code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{beamer}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{pgfpages}
\pgfpagesuselayout{resize to}[a4paper,landscape]
%\pgfpagesuselayout{2 on 1}[a4paper]
%\usetheme{Singapore}
\usetheme{Boadilla}
\usepackage{siunitx}
%\usefonttheme[?options?]{structuresmallcapsserif}
%\definecolor{beamer@blendedblue}{RGB}{203,140,55} % changed this
\definecolor{beamer@blendedblue}{RGB}{0,102,102} % changed this
%\definecolor{beamer@blendedblue}{RGB}{0,153,153} % changed this
\usefonttheme{professionalfonts} %To get the accents aligned correctly, albeit in Computer Modern Roman
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\setbeamertemplate{blocks}[rounded][shadow=true]
\begin{document}
    %-----------------------------------------------------------------New slide ----------------------------------------------------%
    \begin{frame}{Robust Control}
        Known parameters:
        \begin{equation}
            m = \SI[parse-numbers = false, per-mode = symbol]{2}{\kilo\gram},\quad \ell = \SI[parse-numbers = false, per-mode = symbol]{4}{\meter},\quad g = \SI[parse-numbers = false, per-mode = symbol]{9.81}{\meter\per\second^2},\quad b = 1.
        \end{equation}
        For both control techniques, $\mathbf{x}_0 = \begin{bmatrix}\ang{90} & 0\end{bmatrix}^{\textrm{T}}$
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Right now, the numbers are in `san-serif`, even though I have `\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}`. I would like to change them to Computer Modern (Roman) like the others in the math environment. How to do so (it would also be nice if there's a way to change the units and the degree sign in CM(R))?

Comment: With the current version of siunitx the numbers are serif https://i.stack.imgur.com/FOsn9.png